# Целесообразность использования Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, java, java-ee

Доброго всем времени!

Была нужда познакомиться со Spring Framework. Для этого по просьбе знакомой написал сайт (5 страниц). front-end: html/css, javascript, jQuery, ну а back-end: spring MVC + JSP + mySQL.

Все было размещено на VPS.

Может, вопрос и бессмысленный, но просто после разговора с коллегой возникло смятение по выбору back-end-а. Стоило ли использовать указанные технологии для сайта, с БД из 4-5 таблиц, с нагрузкой примерно 50 чел./мес.?

Answer (score 5):

Поверьте, если вы не знаете, нужен ли Вам Spring, значит он вам не нужен. И для такого сайта - да, реально не нужно, хотя в целях саморазвития - почему бы и нет. )

Comment: такой сайт, в принципе, на java писать нецелесообразно

Comment: Ну это спорный вопрос - писать надо, используя тот язык, который лучше знаешь.

Comment: Увы, это кодерский подход, не инженерный - забивать все одним молотком, даже если это не гвозди.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, задача была изучить Spring, чтобы потом его активно применять на практике. Но тут познакомился с веб-программистом, который меня разубедил в вопросе технологий для back-end. Запутавшись, я пришел сюда.
Какие по вашему мнению технологии применять?

Comment: @nightin_gale, как всегда -- самые простые (из удовлетворяющих ТЗ).

Comment: Ответы на вопрос какую технологию применять могут быть такие:
1. Какую лучше знаете.
2. Какую хочет заказчик.
3. Какую хотите изучить.
Все остальное - холливар.